# Show appropriate view based on user permission

Tags: permissions, list-view, groups

I have a document library with different views. Some user must update some columns and other users must update other columns. Is it possible to display different views based on which group user belongs to?

Comment: What is the final effect you  need to achieve? Based on your post, it would seem that you need column level permission (which would include managing permission on the new, edit, view forms and such). Is that the case or you are only trying to assign different list views to different user groups?

Comment: I want to assign different list views to different user group, every body has permission to see columns but they have permission to change some of the columns

Comment: so you will need an edit/new item form that enforces the column level permission. Understood

Comment: You may try this link from Elio
http://www.eliostruyf.com/sharepoint-2007-create-permissions-on-list-views/

Answer (score 3):

Use target audience settings of the web part. Set it to the SharePoint group that can only see the contents of that view. The only trade off is that, when a user is not on that group, he can select the view but will only see a blank white area.

Comment: This worked for me.  For my set up, I have a default view which filters on a People Picker field (person or group) and has a filter set to only show items where the Person field is equal to [Me] - therefore the users will only see their own items.  Other views are restricted by using the Target Audience Settings (Edit Page/Edit Web Part/Advanced/Target Audiences).    However it is worth noting that for the original Question poster's scenario it is still possible to edit all fields by editing the item properties.

Answer (score 1):

What if you create different views and use target audience?

Check this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3730d47f-6ba2-4ffd-ac05-567b042ff5c1/how-to-restrict-permissions-on-list-views?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. let me know if it solves the purpose.
http://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/

Also another solution with Item level permissions for pages library. you can set the pages with the different views and assign them the item level permissions. Refer the below link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433486/How-to-set-view-level-permissions-out-of-the-box-i

Answer (score -1):

There is a nice solution to manage permissions for views and fields:
https://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/

Comment: column permissions, if you have many columns has it any impact on performance?

Comment: Actualy i had some perfomance problem with large count of site groups(more then 5000), but i had no any problems with columns count.