# can we restrict a list view according to the target audience?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a list in which i had created two different views, "view 1" and "view 2" each of which is having different site columns being displayed, I have two share point groups group 1 and group 2, so can I restrict view 1 to be visible to group 1 and view 2 to group 2.?

Comment: It is a duplicate of the existing queston: [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114774/show-appropriate-view-based-on-user-permission][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114774/show-appropriate-view-based-on-user-permission

Comment: Check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4443/is-setting-permissions-on-views-now-possible

Answer (score 0):

you can set the permission on views using the below solution :

https://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/